# mysqldump Cron Job Password less command line scripts with MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql, cron-task

I login into SSH as the Account I will want to eventually run a Cron Job with. (ACCOUNT_NAME)

I then run:

```
mysql_config_editor set --login-path=local --host=localhost --user=MYSQL_USERNAME --password
```

I then type in the password for this username.

I then run:

```
mysql_config_editor print --all
```

It shows this:

```
[local]
user = MYSQL_USERNAME
password = *****
host = localhost
```

I then try:

```
mysql --login-path=local
```

I get this error:

```
Error 1045 (28000); Access denied for user 'MYSQL_USERNAME'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: You are probably using  `--login-path` incorrectly (it creates a group `[USERNAME]` in your config file, and does not define a directory). Run `mysql_config_editor print --all` to see its current content. The file will always be created for (=in the home directory of) the user that is running it, so use the user that runs the cron job (or specify the user in the cron file, set the "HOME"-variable or use some other mean)

Comment: If I run [code]mysql_config_editor print --all[/code] the group [code][USERNAME][/code] is there with the USERNAME and encrypted password under it. I'm just naming the path the same as the username. Then calling as such.Still confused.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. You (usually) do not want a group with the username, because you would need to specify that name before you run mysql so it knows it should use options from this group ("mysqldump" might be a viable groupname, so only mysqldump will use this data). And apart from knowing the group, you need the file to be in the home-directory of the user that executes the cron job (or set the homedirectory-variable as such when you run the cronjob), otherwise mysql(dump) will not find it. Just doing `cd /home/ACCOUNTNAME/` before running the config tool will not do this.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense that I want to create the group logged in as the user that runs the cron job. (I had created this logged in as root previously).

So I logged in as the cron job user and created a path named mysqldump instead:

`mysql_config_editor set --login-path=mysqldump --host=localhost --user=USERNAME --password`

This created a new .mylogin.cnf in my /home/ACOUNTNAME/ directory with group and owner permissions as ACOUNTNAME/ACOUNTNAME

Then I try to run my cron job using:
`mysqldump --login-path=mysqldump USERNAME | gzip > "/home/ACOUNTNAME/backup/DATABASENAME-$(date).sql.gz

Comment: (ran out of comment room, new at this, thanks for your patience)
FYI -previous try also failed

Comment: I think I might have done the opposite of what you were suggesting with mysqldump. Now that I know that I need to create the group logged in as the same cron job user, an example of what would be the correct calls would really be helpful.

Comment: You probably mean `mysqldump --login-path=mysqldump DATABASENAME` instead of `USERNAME`? Have you tried running `mysqldump --login-path=mysqldump DATABASENAME` from that account directly from the command line? This whould work. If that works, add it to the crontab. If it doesn't, post the error. If it doesn't work in the crontab, post the line you are using in the crontab file.

Comment: Yes, I did mean `DATABASENAME`. Still didn't work for me. I edited my initial post to explain exactly what I did and test by simply just connecting to MySQL. (no cron job) I appreciate your patience. Might be a server configuration off. I think what I just did should work.

Comment: Yes it does work now. You can see from the error message that it is taking the username and password from your config file. They are just not valid, so check that useraccount in mysql. It has to exist with that username and host (or the host '%').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my real problem was that I was calling the cronjob from a cpanel account and it had no permissions to access the .mylogin.cnf file in the root.

What I finally did was copy my .mylogin.cnf from the root folder to the account folder (/home/ACCOUNTNAME/), and then change the owner:group permissions to the cpanel account user (ACCOUNTNAME:ACCOUNTNAME) . Then the cronjob from that account was able access the --login-path.

You could probably just login into SSH using the cpanel account instead of root when you create the file (using mysql_config_editor ) and avoid copying the file and changing permissions. For some reason this wasn't working for me.

The final CronJob call that worked was:

```
mysqldump --login-path=CREDSREFERENCE DATABASENAME | gzip > "/home/ACCOUNTFOLDERNAME/backup/DATABASENAME-$(date).sql.gz"
```

Thanks to @wchiquito. His command lines and discussion put me on the right track.

Comment: the call "--login-path=" is a little confusing. It's not actually a directory path.

'--login-path' = is just a reference to a set of login credentials inside of the file .mylogin.cnf

Comment: This helped me. I ran into some unexpected behavior where there was a cron job being run by root producing `ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'sometable' doesn't exist`. I tried querying the table from the shell and it was there. Why? The `.mylogin.cnf` file needed to be in root's home folder (it was in mine where I setup the credentials). Cron couldn't find the credentials as it defaults to look for the file in its home folder.

Comment: I recently had a problem with this regarding some Linux bug saving path passwords that include hash-marks. Apparently, when you enter the password with a hash-mark you need to enclose in quote-marks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. Check the credentials of the user (in my case `mysql_user`) to access MySQL:

```
username@machine $ mysql_config_editor set \
                   --login-path=mysqldump \
                   --host=localhost \
                   --user=mysql_user \
                   --password
Enter password:

username@machine $ ls -l .mylogin.cnf 
-rw------- 1 username username 120 Jan 10 00:01 .mylogin.cnf

username@machine $ mysql_config_editor print --all
[mysqldump]
user = mysql_user
password = *****
host = localhost

username@machine $ mysqldump tbl_name | \
                   gzip > "/path/username/tbl_name-$(date).sql.gz"

username@machine $ ls -l *.sql.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 1276 Jan 10 00:02 tbl_name-Tue Jan 10 00:02:01 UTC 2017.sql.gz

username@machine $ crontab -l -u username
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 1 * * * mysqldump tbl_name | gzip > "/path/username/tbl_name-$(date).sql.gz"
```

Comment: Is it possible that a hashmark or asterisk in the password could be causing the problem?

Comment: @user2032807: Asterisks are for masking the password. `The encryption used by mysql_config_editor prevents passwords from appearing in .mylogin.cnf as cleartext and provides a measure of security by preventing inadvertent password exposure.`. See [4.6.6 mysql_config_editor — MySQL Configuration Utility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-config-editor.html).

Comment: I understand - though there is an actual asterisk in my password. : )

Comment: @user2032807: You should have no problem with the asterisk of your password. My password also includes an asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a problem with this regarding some Linux bug saving path passwords that include hash-marks. Apparently, when you enter the password with a hash-mark you need to enclose in quote-marks.